# How to Get only recent record from the Search Query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a search query where I am getting records from 2 tables

Table A gives client data  , Table B gives transaction number

clientdid is PK in table A and FK in table B . I am using left join to get the data

**QUERY**

```
select a.clientdid, a.clientcode, a.name, b.transactionnumber
from table a
  left join table b on (a.clientdid = b.id )
```

**Output is coming like this .**

| clientdid | clientcode | name | transactionnumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | CLIENTA | S5221S/SO/1062 |
| 100 | 1 | CLIENTA | S5221S/SO/1063 |

**Expected is**

| clientdid | clientcode | name | transactionnumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | CLIENTA | S5221S/SO/1063 |

How can I only get the recent record. I prefer not to use the subquery as this is just one small part

Group concat but didnt get the desired output

Comment: You need to fully specify what defines the "most recent record."

Comment: How do you tell which is the most recent record? Is the transaction number always in the format 'xxxxxx/xx/xxxx' and you want the greatest value by alphabetic order? Then just select `MAX(transactionnumber)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try with `rank`:

```sql
select a.clientdid, a.clientcode, a.name, b.transactionnumber, 
rank() over(partition by a.clientdid order by b.transactionnumber desc) as rn
from table a
left join table b on (a.clientdid = b.id )  
qualify rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join with b again that assumed to have a newer transaction and filtered for that being false. Only the newest transaction per client will suffice that:

```
select a.clientdid, a.clientcode, a.name, b.transactionnumber
from table a
left join table b on (a.clientdid = b.id ) 
left join table b b_older on (a.clientid = b_older.id and b.transactionnumber < b_older.transactionnumber)
where b_older.id is null
```